# Microsoft R Open remote connection to R-Server In-Database

Tags: sql-server-2016, microsoft-r

I'm pretty confused with the different R-Servers. There is the Standalone type and the In-Database type.

What I want is a connection from my R-Studio with Microsoft R Open 3.3.3 to the R Server In-Database type (with mrsdeploy) and not to the Standalone (I did not install the Standalone). Is this even possible? Or is mrsdeploy only working with the standalone type? Because there is no `"Microsoft.RServer.Utils.AdminUtil.dll"` at the In-Database type, where I could configure the webnode and cumputing node.

Answer (score 0):

The in-database type is built into SQL Server 2016 (and later). There's no reason to connect your RStudio to the in-database R services. You would essentially use R Studio to write your code, troubleshoot your code, perfect your code, and then copy and paste your R code as text into SQL stored procedures and queries if you need to.

If you have a standalone R Server (not an in-database type), you can connect your R directly to it and work with data that's SQL or any other format. The whole purpose of the in-database R Services is to have your R script close to your data.

I would start by reading about the differences between SQL Server R Services (In-Database) and R Server (Standalone) on the Microsoft help pages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/sql-server-r-services

I would then read about how to implement R scripts in your stored procedures using sp_execute_external_script.

Hope this helps.